# Как отключить инфу об ошибках MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю проверку на существование строки:

```
$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `type`='".$type."'"));
if(isset($check['id'])) {
...
}
```

Если не существует - выводит на страницу ошибку:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given

Как от этого избавится и есть ли тут уязвимость?

Comment: Юзайте PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем все в одну строчку делать?

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `type`='".$type."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    $check = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    echo $check['id'];
}
```

В этом случае, вам уже не надо проверять $check['id']

**UPD**
Вчера не заметил в вашем вопросе по поводу уязвимостей. Не буду особо оригинальным и так же посоветую перебираться на PDO. Ну, а если использовать обычный подход для работы с БД, то конечно же надо обрабатывать данные при записи в БД: как минимум [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.html), **НО** не менее важно экранировать на выводе. Например:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($check['text']);
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать PDO

Answer (score 1):

уязвимость безусловно есть, вы пихаете переменную прямо в запрос к бд.. (про инъекции забыли?) pdo вам в помощь.
далее - в $check надо писать результат mysql_query, потом проверять, потом делать выборку (в зависимости от результата)

Comment: уязвимость остается даже тогда, когда все заэкранировано?

Comment: конечно, экранирование не панацея поверьте

Answer (score 0):

Перед вставкой $type в запрос переменную нужно обработать, в зависимости от её типа должна быть соответствующая проверка, тогда всё будет безопасно, если int, например

`if(intval($type)!=0)
{
$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`type`='$type'"));
if(isset($check['id'])) {...}
}`

если строка

`if(!empty(mysql_real_escape_string($type)))
{
$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`type`='$type'"));
if(isset($check['id'])) {...}
}`

Comment: Проверки уже есть и на запрос идет строка с уже имеющимся данными, но в таблице этой строки он не находит и выводит ошибку.